SwiftPM XCTest with Xcode
I'm new to Swift and trying it out a bit and decided to use SwiftPM instead of Xcodes own project format.
Package.swift:
// swift-tools-version: 5.10

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "ProjectTestCli",
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-xctest.git", branch: "main"),
    ],
    targets: [
        .executableTarget(
            name: "App"),
        .testTarget(
            name: "AppTests",
            dependencies: [
                .target(name: "App"),
                .product(name: "XCTest", package: "swift-corelibs-xctest"),
            ]),
    ])

SomeTest.swift:
@testable import App
import XCTest

final class SomeTest: XCTestCase {
    override func setUpWithError() throws {}

    override func tearDownWithError() throws {}

    func testSomething() throws {
        XCTAssertEqual("test", "test")
    }
}

When running the test from Xcode by clicking one of the play buttons in the SomeTest.swift file it fails with "No such module 'SwiftFoundation'".
Similar when running it from the command line with "swift test". One of the Libs source files seems to have a problem at "XCTestMain.swift:21:23" where it imports the SwiftFoundation module.
It is a very simple project setup - what is wrong here?
I'm using Xcode Version 15.4 and I'm on Sonoma 14.5.
I'm expecting it to work.

Not sure if it's relevant here but App is a protocol in SwiftUI so you might want to come up with a more original name for your app to avoid any confusion. Also note that it's most common to have an Xcode project for the main app and then use package(s) as a complement rather than having all the code in a package.

The folder names are actually exactly the same as in a vapor project. But still I tried to rename it from App to something else and still the same error. Maybe I should have mentioned that I don't want to write an app for Mac or iOS, but rather this - I don't know how to call that - open thing like a vapor project, which will also run on Linux.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It works now. What I did is simply creating a new project with "swift package init" and then I just added a testTarget in the Package.swift WITHOUT adding an XCTest package dependency manually. I actually don't have any package dependencies right now. It seems to be available already or it works because I'm using Xcode.
